# Grouped bar plot with different sample sizes

Tags: r, barplot

I'm trying to create a grouped barplot in R. The issue I have is that my two groups have different sample sizes (smokers = 50, non-smokers = 20), if I plot them using frequency alone I don't think my barplot will show much due to the difference in sample sizes..

I'm looking to have income on the bottom of the graph in groups, 0 < 5k, 5k <= 10k  etc. and smoker/non-smoker will be the groups. Below is an example of the issue I will have (created in Excel).

[image]

Is there a way I can the values so when I create the plot, the visualisation for each group will be comparable?

Comment: One workaround is to compute the percentages within each smoking status, and then plot the percentages.

Comment: Agreed w/ @Penguin_Knight. You could try a stacked bar chart.

Comment: Hi both, thank you for your response.

I was thinking I needed to use:
> df$income.group <- "0 < x < 25k"[df$eqvinc < 25000]

Is there a way to edit my current data frame to amend the information in the group column?

Comment: Please note that focus on precisely what code to use would lead this question off-topic. See advice on software-specific questions in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to do this in R is secondary. The key question here is what kinds of plot work well. Here is one possibility and there are others.

It may seem at first sight that you need to choose between showing frequencies and showing percents, but you can have it both ways with a **mosaic plot** (or **spineplot** in this case; plenty of other names have been invented in Augsburg).

The non-smokers we suppose to be a healthy pink and the smokers grey at best. The two axes give percent breakdowns, but the areas of the tiles convey frequencies. Departures from independence are shown by departures from vertical alignment.

In this implementation and with this example, we can show the frequencies as extra text; adding text to a graph in this way will divide opinions on good practice.

As first said, software used is incidental, but for the curious I document use of the Stata program `spineplot`. Any good software will serve.

[image]

Comment: My upvote for recommending a mosaic plot. It fits perfectly for the intended purpose. In medical literature, however, I cannot remember having seen one 'in the wild'. The question was asked with regards to R, so I want to add that the most common way to make a mosaic plot in R is the 'vcd' package. I have no doubt though, that there are other good R packages. Unfortunately, ggplot2 is not one of them IIRC.

@Nick Cox: Could you give a hint, what Augsburg has got to do with mosaic plots? I am curious.

Comment: Many workers in this field were students of Antony Unwin in Augsburg: http://rosuda.org/~unwin/

Answer (score 1):

This is your graph, with proportions and confidence intervals :
[image]

This is the code I used (enjoy! Oups, the confidence bars are wrong but you can adapted it!):

```
N=c(rep(50,3),rep(20,3))
Proport=c(20,15,15,5,10,5)/N

data <- data.frame(
  Category=rep(c('Smoker','Non-smoker'), each=3),
  Label=c('0<x<5','5<x<10','10<x<15','0<x<5','5<x<10','10<x<15'),
  Proportion=Proport,  
  SD=sqrt(Proport*(1-Proport)/N)
)

me1=qnorm(0.025,mean=data$Proportion,sd=data$SD)
me2=qnorm(0.975,mean=data$Proportion,sd=data$SD)

mat <- matrix(data$Proportion, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(levels(data$Category),levels(data$Label)))
barx=barplot(mat, beside=T, col = c("blue", "orange", "blue", "orange","blue", "orange"), names.arg = toupper(colnames(mat)), legend.text=TRUE,ylim=c(0,1),xlab="Income",ylab="Proportion",main="Bar plot with 95% confidence intervals")
box()
arrows(barx,me2, barx, me1, angle=90, code=1)
arrows(barx,me1, barx, me2, angle=90, code=1)
```

Comment: As you say, the proportions don't sum to 1 for each income category.